# Updating a python dictionary while adding to existing keys?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I'm looking for the most efficient and pythonic (mainly efficient) way to update a dictionary but keep the old values if an existing key is present. For example...

```
myDict1 = {'1': ('3', '2'), '3': ('2', '1'), '2': ('3', '1')}
myDict2 = {'4': ('5', '2'), '5': ('2', '4'), '2': ('5', '4')}

myDict1.update(myDict2) gives me the following....

{'1': ('3', '2'), '3': ('2', '1'), '2': ('5', '4'), '5': ('2', '4'), '4': ('5', '2')}
```

notice how the key '2' exists in both dictionaries and used to have values ('3', '1') but now it has the values from it's key in myDict2 ('5', '4')?

Is there a way to update the dictionary in an efficient manner so as the key '2' ends up having values ('3', '1', '5', '4')? #in no particular order

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no easy way to do it. You have to iterate keys and merge values.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Seems like you're representing a graph with adjacency list to me... So what if the `'2':('3','1')` and `'2':('5','3')` are merged? Will the result have double `'3'`s in the list?

Comment: @Billiska then {'3': ['1', '5'], '1': ['3'], '5':[3]}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most effective way to do it would be something like this:

```
for k, v in myDict2.iteritems():
    myDict1[k] = myDict1.get(k, ()) + v
```

But there isn't an `update` equivalent for what you're looking to do, unfortunately.

Comment: I will try this method right now and see if it can handle very large dictionaries and get back to you. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Clay I've updated my answer such that you have less iteration overall, it might be worth trying my new solution.  However at some point processing a lot of data is just gonna take a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

What is wrong with 2 in-place update operations?

```
myDict2.update(myDict1)
myDict1.update(myDict2)
```

Explanation:
The first update will overwrite the already existing keys with the values from myDict1, and insert all key value pairs in myDict2 which don't exist.

The second update will overwrite the already existing keys in myDict1 with values from myDict2, which are actually the values from myDict1 itself due to the 1st operation. Any new key value pairs inserted will be from the original myDict2.

This of course is conditional to the fact that you don't care about preserving myDict2

Update: With python3, you can do this without having to touch myDict2

```
myDict1 = {**myDict1, **myDict2, **myDict1}
```

which would actually be same as

```
myDict1 = {**myDict2, **myDict1}
```

Output

```
{'1': ('3', '2'), '3': ('2', '1'), '2': ('3', '1'), '4': ('5', '2'), '5': ('2', '4')}
```

Comment: The 2 in place doesn't work for all cases:

E.g.

<code>
myDict1: { "pg": { "username": "foo", "password": "bar"} }
myDict2: {"pg": {"host": "localhost"}
</code>

<code>
myDict2.update(myDict1)
myDict2:  { "pg": { "username": "foo", "password": "bar"} }
</code>

<code>
myDict1.update(myDict2)
myDict1:  { "pg": { "username": "foo", "password": "bar"} }
</code>

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to merge large dictionaries is to introduce an intermediate object that behaves as though the dicts are merged without actually merging them (see [@Raymond Hettinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259217/4279)):

```
from collections import ChainMap

class MergedMap(ChainMap):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        result = []
        found = False
        for mapping in self.maps:
            try:
                result.extend(mapping[key])
                found = True
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return result if found else self.__missing__(key)

merged = MergedMap(myDict1, myDict2)
```

Whether it is applicable depends on how you want to use the combined dict later.

It uses [`collections.ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.ChainMap) from Python 3.3+ for convenience to provide the full `MutableMapping` interface; you could implement only parts that you use on older Python versions.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a `defaultdict` would help

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict0= {'1': ('3', '2'), '3': ('2', '1'), '2': ('3', '1')}
myDict2 = {'4': ('5', '2'), '5': ('2', '4'), '2': ('5', '4')}
myDict1 = defaultdict(list)
for (key, value) in myDict0.iteritems():
     myDict1[key].extend(value)

for (key, value) in myDict2.iteritems():
     myDict1[key].extend(value)

print myDict1
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['3', '2'], '3': ['2', '1'], '2': ['3', '1', '5', '4'], '5': ['2', '4'], '4': ['5', '2']})
```

Answer (score 0):

No there's no easy way to do it I'm afraid.

The best way is probably iterating and merging. Something like:

```
for key in myDict1.iterkeys():
    # Thank you to user2246674 and Nolen Royalty to help me optimise this in their comments 
    if key in myDict2:
        myDict2[key] = myDict2[key] + myDict1[key]
    else:
        myDict2[key] = myDict1[key]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your answer works like a charm but I have a dictionary with 100000+ keys and it simply takes too long that's why I was looking for an efficient in-place method.

Comment: yup sorry - I've just tried with 200,000 keys and you're right. Takes a while! Sorry :-(

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient to say `if key in myDict2` than `if key in myDict2.iterkeys()`.  `key in myDict2` is O(1) while `key in myDict2.iterkeys()` is O(n) where n is the length of `myDict2`.  I believe this is what @user2246674 was trying to convey.

Comment: this has the exact same effect as myDict2.update(myDict1) which is not what exactly what I'm looking for