# Merging two dictionaries while keeping both the original and the new value for each key

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

In Python, when I merge two dictionaries using the [update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method, any existing keys will be overwritten.

Is there a way to merge the two dictionaries while keeping the original keys in the merged result?

Say we had the following example:

```
dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
```

Can we merge the two dictionaries, such that the result will keep both values for the key `bookC`?

I'd like `dict3` to look like this:

```
{'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': (2,3), 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample input/output?

Comment: Related? [Updating a python dictionary while adding to existing keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745529/updating-a-python-dictionary-while-adding-to-existing-keys)

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen to keys that are present in both dicts?

Comment: @BAH Thanks, added an example

Comment: Would you want the key to return a tuple of values in that case?

Comment: @J2C yes, that would be an option. And, if I can have the key twice that would also be another option

Comment: @Simplicity nope, that would not be a dictionary ;)

Comment: You can't have a dictionary contain two keys of the same value. Keys must be unique. I would question the purpose of the outer code and whether a dictionary is the correct object to store the data you need?

Comment: what about in one line?

Comment: @J2C if you read the question, you'll see the author is not trying to store two of the same key, they're trying to store two values tupled under one key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's alright to keep all values as a list (which I would prefer, it just adds extra headache and logic when your value data types aren't consistent), you can use the below approach for your updated example using a `defaultdict`

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 4}

d3 = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    d3[k].append(v)

for k, v in d3.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
a [1, 2]
d [4]
c [3]
b [2, 3]
```

You also have the below approach, which I find a little less readable:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3,}

d3 = dict((k, [v] + ([d2[k]] if k in d2 else [])) for (k, v) in d1.items())

print(d3)
```

This wont modify any of the original dictionaries and print:

```
{'b': [2, 3], 'c': [3], 'a': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: What about the elements in d2 that are not in d1? Will they get to d3 with the above implementation?

Comment: @EduardoCMB you're right they won't, I realized that when he updated his question. See edited answer with `defaultdict`

Comment: this is the exact thing I just wrote - but the `*zip` call is superfluous. Also just use `d3[k].append(v)`

Comment: @Simplicity, no worries, glad to have helped :)

Comment: what about in one line?

Comment: @Pinocchio, see `d3 = dict(...` etc

Comment: @Bahrom sorry I wasn't clear with what I meant to ask. I meant, in one line like something like `d1 + d2` rather than a (hard to read) list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'a': 10, 'd': 2, 'e': 3}

b.update({key: (a[key], b[key]) for key in set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys())})
b.update({key: a[key] for key in set(a.keys()) - set(b.keys())})

print(b)
```

Output:
{'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': (1, 10)}

Comment: the output should have the key of both `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'a': 10, 'd': 2, 'e': 3}

for k in b:
    if k not in a:
        a[k] = b[k]
```

**Update**

After the update to the question I would agree with BAH's implementation of using a defaultdict with a list

Comment: "Can we merge the two dictionaries, such that the result will keep **both values** for the key bookC?"

Comment: OK, but it doesn't answer the question as it currently stands. It happens sometimes that a question is edited to invalidate an answer. That answer should be changed or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to keep all values as a list, which is not using defaultdict or chain.

Revise the example:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 4}
d3 = {}
for (k, v) in list(d1.items())+list(d2.items()):
    try:
        d3[k] += [v]
    except KeyError:
        d3[k] = [v]
print(d3)
```

Then we have:

```
{'d': [4], 'b': [2, 3], 'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3]}
```

The try statement is used for speed. 
It tries to add the value v with the key k.
In case of KeyError, d3 accepts the new key.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the ordering which I think the other answers don't quite get right. This is Python 3.9:

```
dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
dict3 = dict1 | dict2
dict4 = {key for key in dict1 if key in dict2}
dict5 = {key: (dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in dict4}
result = dict3 | dict5

for item in result:
    print(repr(result[item]))

print(result)


1
2
(3, 2)
4
5
{'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': (3, 2), 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
```

You can then use tuple unpacking:

```
for item in result:
    if  type(result[item]) is tuple:
        print("Value from dict1: {}, value from dict2: {}".format(*result[item]))

Value from dict1: 3, value from dict2: 2
```

And if you want to be crazy and put the result dict on one line:

```
dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}

result = dict1 | dict2 | {key: (dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in {key for key in dict1 if key in dict2}}
```